# Is is possible to instruct ghci to use a concrete type for a constraint when evaluating the type of an expression?

Tags: haskell, types, signature, ghci

I can use ghci to evaluate the type of `fmap`:

```
Prelude> :t fmap
fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

Is there a way I can instruct ghci to bind `f` to a particular instance of `Functor` and print out the resulting type signature. I.e for `[]` it would print

```
(a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

If not, are there any tricks or roundabout ways to achieve the same? This would be particularly handy for deriving type signatures of more complicated expressions and functors (e.g. `(->) a`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is

```
Prelude> :set -XTypeApplications 
Prelude> :t fmap @[]
fmap @[] :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

Comment: And to fix other parameters without fixing the first, you can use underscores, as in `fmap @_ @Int :: Functor f => (Int -> b) -> f Int -> f b`. Use `:set -fprint-explicit-foralls` together with `:type +v` to learn the order of type-level arguments.